# Node.js indexOf not returning correct value

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, indexof

So I built a discord bot that grabs values from a JSON file. Well as the bot grew people started trying to grab values that were not on the JSON file and it kept killing the bot so I added the indexOf function to the bot but when the value is on the JSON file it still displays -1. I have tried everything it seems to get it to grab the correct index number but everything seems to fail.

```js
client.defense = require("./stats/defense.json")

if (message.content.startsWith('s!stats defense')){
        const args1 = message.content.slice(16).split();
        const command1 = args1.shift().toLowerCase();
        editedmessage = command1 
        var index = client.defense[editedmessage].Name.indexOf(editedmessage) 
        if(editedmessage /= ''){
            message.channel.send("I don't know how you ended up in here but good job now DM Toasty");
        } else message.channel.send(index);
```

```js
{
    "aaron ozark": {
      "Name": "Aaron Ozark",
      "Games": 1,
      "Tackles": 1,
      "Sacks": 0,
      "Passesdefended": 0,
      "Interceptions": 0,
      "ForcedFumbled": 0,
      "FumblesRecovered": 0,
      "Touchdowns": 0,
      "Team": "Vipers",
      "position": "WR",
      "FantasyPoints": 0
    },
    "adelie de pengu": {
      "Name": "Adelie De Pengu",
      "Games": 7,
      "Tackles": 27,
      "Sacks": 1,
      "Passesdefended": 3,
      "Interceptions": 2,
      "ForcedFumbled": 0,
      "FumblesRecovered": 0,
      "Touchdowns": 0,
      "Team": "Wallabies",
      "position": "DB",
      "FantasyPoints": 6.5
    },
    "akashi seijuro": {
      "Name": "Akashi Seijuro",
      "Games": 7,
      "Tackles": 24,
      "Sacks": 1,
      "Passesdefended": 2,
      "Interceptions": 3,
      "ForcedFumbled": 0,
      "FumblesRecovered": 1,
      "Touchdowns": 0,
      "Team": "Aztecs",
      "position": "DB",
      "FantasyPoints": 10
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the format of your json file? Is it an array of json objects? Or just a json object? We need to see what it looks like.

Comment: Updated the post to show a sample of the JSON file

Comment: `editedmessage /= ''` are you sure this is correct? It's a "divide and assign" operation equal to `editedmessage =  editedmessage / ''` and the result of this should always be `NaN` since both operands are strings and "string divided by string" is a meaningless mathematical operation.

Comment: Yes that is correct. An example of the command would be is s!stats defense Akashi Seijuro

Comment: Oh i see what you are saying. It is suppose to be does not equal. I need to fix that to be equals... You just solved a problem that I was struggling to figure out

Comment: The issue is that you CANNOT match the name if it's in different capitalisation. If `editedmessage  = "aaron ozark"` then `client.defense[editedmessage].Name` returns `"Aaron Ozark"` but `"Aaron Ozark".indexOf("aaron ozark")` is `-1` since these are two different strings based on capitalisation.

Comment: So i should use args1?

Comment: I don't know what you expect to get. What is `index` supposed to be if this code was correct? At best it seems that it will always be `0` if the name matches but...that doesn't really make much sense as a return value.

Comment: The next thing is to if it = -1 it will display something different than try to display stats for a player that isn't there and tell them that the player isn't in the defensive stats database

Comment: But what should the result be when it's not `-1`?

Comment: It will display the stats when not -1 that is just a portion of the code